# how to boot from dvd on windows on mac?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

I have a windows 7 image from my a PC. I setup bootcamp (on my mac), but when I try to restore the image it states I must first create a startup disk, so I do then the computer reboots and the computer never boots from the dvd. How can I boot from this windows recovery DVD that I created? Because apparently that is the only way I can recover this windows image is to boot from the DVD.
It states,
To restore this computer windows needs to format the drive that the windows recovery environment is currently running on. To continue with the restore shutdown this computer and delete it from a Windows installation disk or a system repair disk and then try the restore again.

I created the DVDs, but it won't boot from disc.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to wipe out your current installation of Windows and reinstall it, it's easiest to use the Apple Boot Camp utility on your Mac OS partition.

Here are instructions if you're unsure how to do this

- Hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while your Mac is booting
- Select your Mac OS partition and sign in if prompted
- Open Boot Camp Assistant from Applications > Utilities
- Follow the prompts to remove Windows

When complete you can launch Boot Camp Assistant again to reinstall Windows

Comment: I'm trying to restore a windows image. Please read the question before answering.